# Compiler Error in inline Assembly error:- C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found 'newline'

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I was testing some C code and came across this strange
compiler error

The following code would not compile

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int length=6;    
    __asm
    {
        mov eax,length
    }
}
```

Visual Studio reports the following error

```
test.c(7) : error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; 
found 'newline'
```

However, I noticed if I changed the name of the variable to something else say `lengths` then everything was fine, the following code compiles without any difficulty

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int lengths=6;    
    __asm
    {
        mov eax,lengths
    }
}
```

I tried with other compilers such as Digital Mars and Intel Compiler, but everywhere the first code cannot be compiled.

What can be the issue ?  Is there another definition for `length` elsewhere.

I would also like to add that this is a single file, not a project so
there cannot be any multiple declarations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wxh0awwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Specifically

> The LENGTH, SIZE, and TYPE operators have a limited meaning in inline assembly. They cannot be used at all with the DUP operator (because you cannot define data with MASM directives or operators). But you can use them to find the size of C or C++ variables or types:

Answer (score 8):

I think the reason may be because [length](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) is a member function

Also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wxh0awwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says:

> The **LENGTH**, SIZE, and TYPE operators have a limited meaning in inline
>   assembly. They cannot be used at all with the DUP operator (because
>   you cannot define data with MASM directives or operators). But you can
>   use them to find the size of C or C++ variables or types:
>
> The **LENGTH** operator can return the number of elements in an array. It
>   returns the value 1 for non-array variables.

Comment: But it would have been better if the compiler notified that directly instead of showing a mysterious error that it found a newline.

Comment: If you would like the compiler to catch that, then you should suggest it to them or file it as a bug on Microsoft connect http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio